Domain and DNS records
I bought a domain name from a provider and hosted my website on github (its a static website).  this didn't support https so I have used cloud flare's nameservers and I was given secured connection (https).
From today visitors to my site are receiving the below error message.  (I've waited 24hrs for it to propagate)

If you are the web site owner, it is possible you have reached this
page because:
The IP address has changed. There has been a server misconfiguration.
The site may have been moved to a different server. If you are the
owner of this website and were not expecting to see this page, please
contact your hosting provider.


Welcome.  I've tried to tidy up your post because it was quite difficult to read.  Please check in case I've changed the meaning.     You may also want to add more about your Cloudflare configuration, and if HTTP still works if you use something like your "hosts" file to point directly to the original site.

Also, did you just use Cloudflares nameservers, or did you also do some configuration on Cloudflare to get them to proxy to the old site?

Check your current Github IP and account, and ensure it works directly. Then go to CloudFlare, review your DNS settings, and check that they are pointing at the correct destination
